# ASP.NET Postback problems in IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, postback

I am working locally on an `ASP.NET` site and am experiencing problems with `postbacks` in `IE8`.

I have a page with a `repeater` that builds a table and each row has a `LinkButton` on it that is used to delete that row.

In `FireFox` and `Chrome`, the button works as expected - the forms posts back and all the values from the form are available for processing. In IE8, the form posts back but the forms collection is empty, except for the button that initiated the `postback`.

This is a problem because

1. it's odd and I don't understand and
2. I use the values from the posted back form to rebuild some business objects (I don't store them in `viewstate` or `session` but rebuild them from scratch based upon values input by user in form). When I post back from `FF/Chrome`, the full form is there (e.g. Request.Form.AllKeys has, say, 60 items) and I can derive the values for my business object. When I post back from IE, my form is practically empty and my rebuilding code fails (e.g. **`Request.Form.AllKeys`** has, say, only 9 items instead of the expected 60).

I am at a loss to explain why there is this difference in the contents of the form collection upon `postback` between `FF/Chrome` and `IE` and would greatly appreciate any insight/help in this regard.

I've tried to break the issue down as I see it - if any further info is required, please let me know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this - turns out I had a form nested within the main form on my master page. Removed it and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem sounds unusual and is not something I've ever come across. Whilst I can't help directly, I'd recommend using [Fiddler - Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to examine the HTTP traffic as a means to diagnosing what is going on. To quote, "Fiddler is freeware and can debug traffic from virtually any application, including Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, and thousands more..."

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked out the traffic with Fiddler and it confirms what I saw - that the postback data from firefox contains all the form elements (and thus I am able to reconstruct my business object just fine) and from IE8 the postback only contains the LinkButton...

Comment: Just a wild guess, but have you validated your HTML and checked you have all the correct closing tags? Sometimes a missing closing tag can screw-up posted data.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem in IE8 in Windows 2008 and the solution was related to User Right escalations.

On Windows 2008 Machine I had to go to:

Start > administrative Tools > Local Security Policy > Local Policies > Security Option

then select "User Account Control : Admin Approval Mode for Build-in Administrator account"

Select Enable & then Apply.

Thanks
Anugrah