# IE8 Post Body Becomes Empty after form submission

Tags: apache, coldfusion, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs, http-post

Okay here is our setup:

Simple form being submitted via AJAX using Prototype 1.7 to a Apache server captured by ColdFusion. (We have noticed similar bugs on pages that submit form data in the conventional way but these pages are used far less.)

Some of our clients are reporting an error. After looking through the logs and doing live testing from their machine Firebug Light is reporting that the request was being sent with the post data.

However on the server side the post data is not present in raw logs or ColdFusion's FORM object or in GetHttpRequestData().

This problem has been isolated to IE only even when running Chrome Frame and is intermittent.

We can not reproduce this error with our IE8 installs on our machines OR on their machines running Firefox or Chrome.

Any thoughts on this extremely difficult bug to track down?

Comment: Is it possible the URL you're posting to is being redirected? E.g. `/target` vs `/target/`?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this issue. There are no redirects taking place, when monitored in firebug lite or firebug in firefox. Further there are no redirects taking place in the "MVC" logic of the Coldfusion application or apache (.htaccess) or programmed inside of CF administrator.

Comment: Does the page validate correctly using an html validator? Perhaps it's a invalid tag nesting that is being misinterpreted by IE. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Two possible issues turned up in a Google search. @jfrobishow already alluded to one of them - [invalid HTML can cause IE8 to not handle forms properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3441673/603502). Another (peculiar) cause of this issue was with [an Apache module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4428740/603502).

Comment: Oh, and one more thing with IE, although probably not relevant to your issue because it's occurring on non-AJAX forms as well. We recently had an issue with AJAX requests in IE where we needed to add a cache busting variable to the end of the URL we were sending POST (or maybe GET, I am not sure...) requests to.

Comment: "Does the page validate correctly using an html validator" - yes

Comment: Believe me I have google and consulted on this issue with many talented people The apache module is not the cause as we went down that road.

Comment: POST AJAX requests do not require the "cache busting" random string to be attached, only GET requests do. Besides any JS lib worth its salt has that built in ;)

Comment: Currently we are looking into the not well documented yet fairly wide spread reports of the NTLM bug in IE where they will not send POST data read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385341/post-variables-coming-through-empty-in-ie7-for-one-subfolder and here http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-March/027283.html we have already done the steps to suggested and are monitoring our logs

Comment: Sorry if I sounded condescending - that was not intended. I just wanted to let you know where I found the info I was posting. Good luck!

Comment: @s992 No love lost bro thanks for helping, I have been doing this for 10+ years and this is the single strangest thing I have ever seen! I really appreciate your thoughts and insight. Did you look at the 2 links I posted? Any thoughts on those? Have you ever seen that before? Thanks a million!

Comment: Wish I had some more advice, this is definitely a bizarre issue. Is there any possibility that you could have your users install [this MS update](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=831167)? It was linked from the Ruby list message.

Comment: right i agree that we could probably do that however it does not seem a viable solution to the problem. This is a web based app that is doing nothing extraordinary and relying on a client side fix seems like a maintenance nightmare, not to mention extremely inconvenient to our clients/new clients... This is the first time I have seen this issue in 10+ years... #frustrating!

Comment: Tim, did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an HTTP proxy involved in this somewhere?  We have had issues in the past, I can't recall the details, but I know that it had something to do with using AJAX to POST.  The proxy was configured such that a certain combination of headers would make it misbehave.  Take a good look at the HTTP headers coming from the browser, comparing one that works and one that doesn't.